# How to check if a class implements an interface, with respecting supersets?

Tags: delphi, oop, interface, com

I am learning about COM and Interfaces and have following experimental code:

```
type
  IA = interface(IInterface)
  ['{C9C5C992-3F67-48C5-B215-7DCE6A61F0E8}']
  end;

  IB = interface(IA)
  ['{F1799437-AD12-471B-8716-F1D93D1692FC}']
  end;

  IC = interface(IB)
  ['{01780E8C-C47D-468E-8E42-4BFF3F495D51}']
  end;

  TBO = class(TInterfacedObject, IB)
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: TBO;
  a: IInterface;
begin
  x := TBO.Create;
  IInterface(x)._AddRef;

  if Assigned(TBO.GetInterfaceEntry(IA)) then memo1.lines.add('GetInterfaceEntry IA: OK'); // Why not?
  if Assigned(TBO.GetInterfaceEntry(IB)) then memo1.lines.add('GetInterfaceEntry IB: OK');
  if Assigned(TBO.GetInterfaceEntry(IC)) then memo1.lines.add('GetInterfaceEntry IC: OK');

  if x.QueryInterface(IA, a)=S_OK then memo1.lines.add('QueryInterface TA: OK'); // Why not?
  if x.QueryInterface(IB, a)=S_OK then memo1.lines.add('QueryInterface TB: OK');
  if x.QueryInterface(IC, a)=S_OK then memo1.lines.add('QueryInterface TC: OK');

  if Supports(TBO, IA) then memo1.lines.add('Supports TA: OK'); // Why not?
  if Supports(TBO, IB) then memo1.lines.add('Supports TB: OK');
  if Supports(TBO, IC) then memo1.lines.add('Supports TC: OK');

  if Supports(x, IA, a) then memo1.lines.add('Supports(2) TA: OK'); // Why not?
  if Supports(x, IB, a) then memo1.lines.add('Supports(2) TB: OK');
  if Supports(x, IC, a) then memo1.lines.add('Supports(2) TC: OK');
end;
```

Output:

```
GetInterfaceEntry IB: OK
QueryInterface TB: OK
Supports TB: OK
Supports(2) TB: OK
```

But I need:

```
GetInterfaceEntry IA: OK
GetInterfaceEntry IB: OK
QueryInterface TA: OK
QueryInterface TB: OK
Supports TA: OK
Supports TB: OK
Supports(2) TA: OK
Supports(2) TB: OK
```

I understand that `IB` is a superset of `IA` due to the Interface inheritance. In my understanding, since `TBO` implements `IB`, it automatically implements `IA`. But why does `Supports()`, `QueryInterface()`, `GetInterfaceEntry()` return false?

How do I query if `TBO` implements `IA` directly OR indirectly, i.e. by implementing a superset of `IA`? I need both, a static class function like `GetInterfaceEntry` and a dynamic object reference variant like `QueryInterface`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755044/in-delphi-how-can-you-check-if-an-iinterface-reference-implements-a-derived-but

Comment: Consider `IA = interface`, `IA1 = interface(IA)` and `IA2 = interface(IA)`. Now `TAggregate = class(TInterfacedObject, IA1, IA2)` in which both IA1 and IA2 are delegated: `property ImplIA1: IA1 read FIA1 implements IA1;` and `property ImplIA2: IA2 read FIA2 implements IA2;` Now if you ask an instance of `TAggregate` for its `IA` interface, which implementation should it return? The point is interface "inheritence" is not really inheritence. So the object doesn't implement an "ancestor" interface unless it does so explicitly.

Comment: @CraigYoung An answer expanding on that would be useful.

Comment: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29779

Comment: @CraigYoung Thank you very much for this example. It is VERY helpful to understand why the explicit naming is required.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Was this feature just introduced in Delphi.NET or was it later also made available for the regular Delphi ?

Comment: This behaviour has been in Delphi as long as interfaces, AFAIR. Because it's a COM compatibility issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `ID = interface(IA, IB)` does not compile in Delphi 6. I haven't tested it in XE6 because I have it only installed at work.

Comment: OK, misunderstood your Q. The article link is to point out what they say about COM interfaces. Ignore the .net parts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The joys of doing something late at night. I didn't have the time for a full answer. I'm expanding on it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known quirk of Delphi.  Even though `IB` inherits from `IA`, `TBO` must explicitly specify both `IA` and `IB` in order for `Supports()` to retrieve both interfaces.

```
TBO = class(TInterfacedObject, IA, IB)
```

I forget the technical reason for this.  Something to do with a limitation in how the compiler generates the interface table for `TBO`.  It does not automatically include inherited interfaces.

Comment: Does that mean that Delphi considers IB to contain all the stuff that IA contains, or is this simply an oddity of the way reflection works in Delphi?

Comment: Is it possible to write an alternative function which solves this problem without changing the class definition, i.e. an alternative for `GetInterfaceEntry`? The algorithm could be following: (1) I could find all interfaces of `TBO` by querying `GetInterfaceTable`, **(2) then I need to detect that `IA` is the parent of `IB`** and finally (3) if `IA` is the requested IID, it is indirectly supported. (4) this will be repeated until there is no parent Interface anymore. The problem is #2: How do I find out the parent Interface of `IB` (like `TObject.ClassParent` for Interfaces)?

Comment: @rinntech Simply put `TBO` does not support `IA`

Comment: It's not a quirk of Delphi. It's a reflection of the fact that Delphi interfaces are really COM interfaces.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree, Rinntech. Just fix the declaration of `TBO` so that it mentions *all* the interfaces it supports. Interface inheritance isn't like class inheritance. Rather than an *is-a* relationship, it's a *has-all-the-same-members-in-the-same-order-as* relationship.

Answer (score 6):

As [Marco Cantù explains here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755089/224704): Interface "inheritance" is not like class inheritance, and in fact it would probably be better to refer to it as interface extension.

There are some serious anomalies that arise if we were to assume a class automatically implemented a base interface.

Consider:

```
IA = interface
<guid>
end;
IA1 = interface(IA)
<guid>
end;
IA2 = interface(IA)
<guid>
end;
```

And a class that aggregates both IA1 and IA2 in which both are delegated:

```
TAggregate = class(TInterfacedObject, IA1, IA2)
private
  FIA1: IA1;
  FIA2: IA2;
protected
  property ImplIA1: IA1 read FIA1 implements IA1; 
  property ImplIA2: IA2 read FIA2 implements IA2;
end;
```

Now if you ask an instance of TAggregate for its IA interface, which implementation should it return?

The point is interface "inheritance" is not really inheritance. So the object doesn't implement an "ancestor" interface unless it does so explicitly.

---

There are a few other things to observe:

If you add a method `procedure MethodIA;` to the IA interface and **do** also explicitly add `IA` as an interface on `TAggregate`, the code would not compile. You'd get the error:

> Undeclared indentifier: 'MethodIA'

You would have to either add `MethodIA` directly onto the class, or choose which of `FIA1` or `FIA2` to delegate the implementation to. E.g. Choosing FIA2:

```
  property ImplIA: IA2 read FIA2 implements IA;
```

This property declaration shows the way in which Delphi does recognise interface *is-a* relationships. I.e. not through an implementation class, but rather an interface reference.

NOTE: Even at compile-time, the compiler will not assume a class implements a base interface unless explicitly stated.

```
TIA1Implementor = class(TInterfacedObject, IA1)
protected
  procedure MethodIA;
end;

var
  LImplObj: TIA1Implementor;
  LA1: IA1;
  LA: IA;
begin
  LImplObj := TIA1Implementor.Create;
  LA1 := LImplObj; //Valid: TIA1Implementor implements IA1
  LA := LImplObj; //Does not compile: TIA1Implementor does not implement IA
  LA := LA1; //Valid: IA1 is an extension of IA
end;
```

At compile-time the extension is known, and assigning an **extension reference** to its base is perfectly legal (without any casting or "supports" checks). But assigning directly from the object reference is not.

---

Interestingly, the `TypInfo` unit shows that interface types do know about their "parent" interface.

```
PTypeData = ^TTypeData;
TTypeData = packed record
  case TTypeKind of
    tkInterface: (
      IntfParent : PPTypeInfo; { ancestor }
      IntfFlags : TIntfFlagsBase;
      Guid : TGUID;
      IntfUnit : ShortStringBase;
     {PropData: TPropData});
```

However given the discussion above I'm not sure how this knowledge could be of benefit at run-time. I'd far rather favour compile-time checking.

Comment: +1 I think it would be valuable to mention the role that COM plays in all of this.