# Resolve naming conflicts caused by interface inheritance in Delphi

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface

If i have these 3 interfaces

```
unit Interfaces;

interface
type
  IA = interface['{86367399-1601-4FDD-89CF-362E762D948E}']
  procedure doSomething;
end;

  IB = interface['{070B9364-4A57-4E5A-BBA7-FBF1C6A48C5A}']
  procedure doSomething;
end;

  IC =interface(IB)['{DAC8021C-42CB-40EC-A001-466909044EC3}']
  procedure doSomething;
end;

implementation

end.
```

How do i resolve naming conficts in a class that implements IA and IC?
I have no problem with IA and IC but how do i implement IB?

```
type
   myClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IA, IC)
    procedure doASomething;
    procedure doBSomething;
    procedure doCSomething;
    procedure IA.doSomething = doASomething;
    //        ???            = doBSomething;
    procedure IC.doSomething = doCSomething;

  end;
```

Comment: Does it really make sense for an extension of `IB` (namely `IC`) to redeclare an identical method? Since `IC` extends `IB`, `procedure doSomething;` is already available. As a client using an implementation of `IC`, how would you call IC's `doSomething` differently from IB's `doSomething`?

Comment: @CraigYoung `(intf as IB).doSomething()` or `(intf as IC).doSomething()`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, that's not what I'm referring to, but I can understand the confusion. `IC` has 2 identical `doSomething`s: Its own, and the one from the interface it extends. So how would a client indicate which of those 2 to call? If an object implements _only_ `IC` and not `IB`, then `(intf as IB)` would be invalid. Also, if an object _did implement both_ `IB` and `IC`, then it would need to provide access to 3 separate `doSomething`s; and how would a client differentiate all 3?

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't implement `IB`. So there's no way to use a method resolution clause for an interface that is not implemented by that class. So, you might imagine that the easy way out is to implement that interface:

```
type
  myClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IA, IB, IC)
    procedure doASomething;
    procedure doBSomething;
    procedure doCSomething;
    procedure IA.doSomething = doASomething;
    procedure IB.doSomething = doBSomething;
    procedure IC.doSomething = doCSomething;
  end;
```

But this fails to compile also. The error is:

```
[dcc32 Error]: E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IB.doSomething
```

I conclude that there is no way for you to implement these interfaces directly. I think that the only way you could square this particular circle would be to [use an `implements` clause to delegate implementation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Implementing_Interfaces_by_Delegation). For instance:

```
type
  myClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IA, IB, IC)
  private
    FA: IA;
    FB: IB;
    FC: IC;
    property A: IA read FA implements IA;
    property B: IB read FB implements IB;
    property C: IC read FC implements IC;
  end;
```

Obviously you'd need to initialise the fields `FA`, `FB` and `FC`, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

This isn't a very satisfactory solution. If I were in your place, I'd be looking very hard for a solution that avoided the name clashes in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As per my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582426/resolve-naming-conflicts-caused-by-interface-inheritance-in-delphi#comment45480761_28582426):
Does it really make sense for an extension of `IB` (namely `IC`) to redeclare an identical method? Since `IC` extends `IB`, `procedure doSomething;` is already available. As a client using an implementation of `IC`, how would you call IC's `doSomething` differently from IB's `doSomething`?

So if you do the following, you should have no trouble.

```
IC =interface(IB)['{DAC8021C-42CB-40EC-A001-466909044EC3}']
  //procedure doSomething; //Don't redeclare an existing method in an extension.
end;

type
   myClass = class(TInterfacedObject,
     //Explicitly state that you're implementing IB
     IA, IB, IC)

     procedure doASomething;
     procedure doBSomething;
     procedure doCSomething;
     procedure IA.doSomething = doASomething;
     //And you'll be able to define IB's method resolution.
     procedure IB.doSomething = doBSomething;
     procedure IC.doSomething = doCSomething;
   end;
```

You may also find some of the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24705061/224704) and answers useful, as it discusses why you need to explicitly state which interfaces a class implements.