# Interface delegation not working when using derived interfaces

Tags: delphi

In Delphi Seattle 10 I'm trying to delegate the implementation of an interface using the `implements` keyword, but when an interface derived from the first one is also included in the class declaration, the delegation is not accepted.

Compilation of the code below fails with a "Missing implementation of interface method IInterface1.DoSomethingFor1" message. If I remove the IInterface2 from the class declaration, the code compiles. If I derive IInterface2 from something else then IInterface1 it also compiles.

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I accomplish this?

```
type
  IInterface1 = interface(IInterface)
    ['{03FB3E2E-C0DD-4E17-B6CD-D333E1E7255E}']
    procedure DoSomethingFor1;
  end;

  Iinterface2 = interface(IInterface1)
    ['{89C266E2-2816-46AD-96AA-DD74E78A4D1E}']
  end;

  T1 = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface1, IInterface2)
  private
    Fi1: IInterface1;
  public
    property I1_Delegate: IInterface1 read Fi1 implements IInterface1;
  end;
```

Comment: Related, but not duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24705061/224704 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28582426/224704

Comment: As well as those there is an *exact* duplicate :) the answer to which also explains the reason the compiler requires that an implementation of a derived interface also requires implementation (not delegation) of any base interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly implement both `IInterface1` and `IInterface2`. You only implement the former. Hence the compilation error. Your implementing class should look like this instead:

```
type
  TImplementingClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface1, IInterface2)
  private
    Fi2: IInterface2;
  public
    property I2_Delegate: IInterface2 read Fi2 implements IInterface1, IInterface2;
  end;
```

Comment: I added the IInterface1 implementation to the class declaration thinking it was necessary to delegate the implementation, but seeing this it turns out I can leave out the use of IInterface1 intirely in the class declaration. Implementing Interface2 is enough.

Comment: but the error message is said to be "Missing implementation of interface method **IInterface1**.DoSomethingFor1" not "Missing implementation of interface method **IInterface2**.DoSomethingFor1"...